# Generating textbox and its id dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a dataTable which contains two columns. The first column contains some list of names and the second column contains an empty text box against each name. These text boxes are created dynamically. I want to generate id for each text box dynamically. I tried with the following code:

```
jQuery("#table_projection_value").dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": "includes/inc-projection-db.php?mode=projection_dataTable",
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "aTargets": [0],
                        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                            return data + '<input type="hidden" class="user_id" name="user_id[]" id="user_id" value="' + row[4] + '">';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "aTargets": [1],
                        "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                            return '<input type="text" class="form-control text-right projected_value" name="projected_value[]" id="projected_value_' + row[4] + '_' + data + '" onchange="change();">';
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            jQuery("#table_projection_value").on("draw.dt", function(){
                jQuery("#projected_value").each(function(i, e){
                    //var controlid = "#" + jQuery(this).prop("id");
                    //alert(controlid);
                    //var arr = controlid.split("_");
                    $'<span></span>'),{
                        "class": "arr",
                        "id": "id_" + i 
                    }).appendTo(this);
                });
            });
```

But the thing is, I get the id for each text box as undefined. So, how can I do that? I'm new to this.[This is what I get as id for the text box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC2Qh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that row[4] is a valid value?

And you have some syntax erors in your code, use this instead:

```
$('<span></span>',{
  "class": "arr",
   id: "id_" + i 
}).appendTo(this);
```

Comment: I don't know whether row[4] is a valid value. I don't know what value to provide instead. Can you provide me with the valid value and answer? I wrote this with an example.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want but if you just want the code to work you need to have an array named row with at least five values in it.  

So you can use   
  `var row = ['one','two','three','four','five'];`

Comment: This is what I want: I have to display a datatable with two columns. The first column contains a list of names which are taken from the database and the second column contains text boxes. There will be an empty text box against each name. After entering a value in one text box and when I place the cursor on another text box to enter a value, the value along with the name and it's hidden ID should get saved in the database. Also, when I edit that value, it should get updated, should not get inserted as a new one. Got my requirement?